# How to add blend modes to emission shader node

Tags: node-editor, emission

Is there a way I can add a Blend mode node to connect to the emission node, and make the object beneath blend with the above object which has the emission.

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Do you mean the 'overlay, screen, hard light' blend modes in the MixRGB node?

Comment: Yes, I also uploaded a sample for better comprehension. If Possible I'd like to choose a blend mode which shows the details of the object below, like the one in PS: https://ibb.co/crpcSvc

Comment: Hey :). The blend modes are done using simple math (comparing existing pixel values). Eevee is physics based, so you need a physics based approach... something *very* different :))

Comment: OK, thanks for the info!